# Dispatch fails with Proxy that requires authentication: Remotely Closed Connection

Tags: java, http, authentication, dispatch, asynchttpclient

What is happening when I use dispatch to make a GET request? I can use a proxy, but I cannot use a proxy that requires authentication.

This works:

```
val ps = new ProxyServer(host, port)
val svc = request.setProxyServer(ps)
val resp = Http(svc > as.String)
```

This fails:

```
val ps = new ProxyServer(host, port)
val svc = request.setProxyServer(ps).as_!(user, pass)
val resp = Http(svc > as.String)
```

The error is:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:342)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.abort(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1418)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.channelClosed(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1485)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:142)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:570)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:371)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelClosed(HttpClientCodec.java:221)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:468)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:375)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val svc = request.setProxyServer(ps).as_!(user, pass)
```

Is setting the user and password for the request, not the proxy

You should instantiate ProxyServer with user and password info :

```
ProxyServer(String host, int port, String principal, String password)
```

[reference](https://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/ProxyServer.html)

In your example:

```
val ps = new ProxyServer(host, port, user, pass)
val svc = request.setProxyServer(ps)
val resp = Http(svc > as.String)
```